# Why is the `MUL` keyword showing up under the `Key` column for the `show columns from Employee` mysql command?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

When I execute `show columns from Employee` in MySQL for the following tables ...

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    departmentId TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
        COMMENT "CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (departmentId) REFERENCES Department(id)",
    firstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    ext SMALLINT UNSIGNED NULL,
    hireDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    leaveDate DATETIME NULL,
    INDEX name (lastName, firstName),
    INDEX (departmentId)
)

CREATE TABLE Department (
    id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(40),
    UNIQUE (name)
)
```

... why is the keyword `MUL` appearing in the result set for the column `lastName` (as well as for `departmentId`) and not for `firstName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MUL` as opposed to `PRI` and `UNI` means a non unique index and is shown for the **first** (or the only column) in an index when you issue a `DESCRIBE` or `SHOW COLUMNS` command.

The only exception to this is

> If more than one of the Key values applies to a given column of a table, Key displays the one with the highest priority, in the order PRI, UNI, MUL.

`firstName` is a **second** column in the composite index `name` and therefore `MUL` is not being displayed for it.

Further reading  [SHOW COLUMNS Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html)

Comment: Oops... thank you for pointing out the correct command. I have updated the question.

Comment: Secondly, thank you for mentioning "..is shown for the first (or the only column) in an index..", but where does it say that in the link that you provided? I can't find that statement. Thirdly, would you be kind enough to explain what the `index` keyword is doing in the above `create table`... I can't seem to find anything that makes sense online at the moment. Thank you!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Scroll down to the explanation of `Key` column of the output and the read `If Key is MUL, the column is the first column of a non unique index...`

Comment: To see what `INDEX` is doing in `CREATE TABLE` statement look up [CREATE TABLE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html). It obviously allows you to define indexes that you want to have on that table once the table is created.

Comment: Honestly, that documentation is a bit overwhelming for me at the moment. I need an introductory level text explaining the basic concepts of `index`.

Comment: Okay I get it now! Indexes are best used on columns that are frequently used in where clauses, and in any kind of sorting, such as "order by". https://www.howtoforge.com/when-to-use-indexes-in-mysql-databases

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped. Good luck.